# iPhone development - calling protocol methods (not working)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, protocols

Classes: Main, Modal, and Table

I declare a protocol in the main class and call that method from both the modal class and table class. Only the modal class is able to call the method. The table class just ignores method call (which is written identically to the modal class - it doesn't call it and doesn't give an error).

What could be the problem?

TL;DR: Is there anything that would limit a class from calling protocol methods?

Comment: how about helping us out with a bit of code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Guess: your reference inside the main object to the table object is `nil`.

Comment: The problem could be.... we don't have enough data to work with here

Comment: @quixoto Does there have to be a reference inside the main object for it to work?

Comment: @Andrew whatever reference you're using to call the method is nil. That's pretty much the only way it'd behave like this.

Comment: @KennyWinker Was setting the delegate incorrectly - thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you set the delegate right, and the different between your Modal and table. I don't think there is anything different which may influent the use of protocol between Modal and Table.